# Netplan error in network definition bonding

Tags: networking, netplan, interface, network-bonding

Copied the example on netplans site and have issues with the interfaces not defined. Below is my config that i'm using. I no longer have internet access on that machine. This was working but rebooted and now it's broken again.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        -  enp0s25
        -  enp8s0
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: enp0s25
```

Thanks!
GD

Answer (score 2):

Netplan will refuse to use physical devices which are not defined at all in the config, and will consider it an error.

A correct config would look like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25: {}
    enp8s0: {}
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp0s25
        - enp8s0
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: enp0s25
```

Comment: That did the trick. I do get another error saying that the bond0: bond already has a primary slave:  I removed the primary: part of the code and it applied the config. I'm not sure if i need that 100% or not but i have access to the internet again on that machine. So a step in the right direction. Thank you for your assistance.